# Why can butane lighters only be refilled in an upside down position?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

The most  common answer I hear is that the reason it is filled in a manner akin to this:

[image]

is because butane is heavier than air, but why should that matter if the butane escapes the canister by getting propelled out of the nozzle at high speed? shouldn't it work if a lighter is getting refilled upright too due to the by butane being expelled out if the nozzle against gravity?

Additionally, I have heard answers mentioning that inside a butane canister there are butane in gaseous and liquid form, as a result it has to be upside down so that the gaseous butane pushed the liquid butane into the lighter reservoir, but couldn't it also be filled in upright position because the gaseous butane will just flow into the lighter and turn into liquid  (in short, if liquid butane stays liquid inside the lighter reservoir, then shouldn't gas butane that enters the lighter also turn into liquid)?

Comment: What do the clear body lighters contain? a liquid or a gas?

Comment: The clear lighter contains Liqid butane

Comment: So what do you want to transfer?

Comment: I want to understand why these lighters can only be filled when upside down, not when they are in upright position.

Comment: Does liquid float on gas or gas float on liquid?

Comment: gas floats on liquid thats for sure

Comment: So which do you want to transfer to the empty lighter?

Comment: @SolarMike Why don't you just post an answer?

Comment: @Chris_abc because getting the OP to think is more productive than just posting a banal answer.

Comment: You're assuming OP didn't think yet. Imo it's a bit patronizing.

Comment: @SolarMike That is my question, cant we transfer the gaseous butane inside the canister into the lighter reservoir where it turns into liquid?

Comment: @Redox it's not the lighter that determines the orientation ... it is the refill canister ... liquid is being transferred, not gas

Comment: The second part of my question was, if liquid butane stays liquid inside the lighter reservoir, then why cant gaseous butane be transferred by flowing into the lighter reservoir and turning into liquid form?